# How to check if requests.get() is called in a method using unittest.mock

Tags: python, python-mock

I am struggling to wrap my head around the unittest.mock docs and the many examples on SO.

I have a class with a method:

**my_class.py**

```
import requests

class MyClass:

   def do_stuff(do_it=True):
       if do_it:
          requests.get('https://someapi.com')
```

And I want a unit test that checks that `do_stuff` tries to call the api using `unittest.mock`

I have a test (very simplified):

**test_my_class.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestMyClass(TestCase)

    def test_do_stuff_uses_api(self):
        MyClass().do_stuff()
        # How to assert that requests.get() method was called once?
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the package `requests_mock`

https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#called

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests_mock

class TestMyClass(TestCase)

    def test_do_stuff_uses_api(self):
        with requests_mock.mock() as m:
            m.get('https://someapi.com', json={....})
            MyClass().do_stuff()
            history = m.request_history
            self.assertEqual(len(history), 1, "Should have been called once")
```